# Appending to Requests JSON result

Tags: python, json

Using Requests to return JSON from an API.
Assigning the parts of the result I need to variables - working fine.

```
for i in searchResult['inventoryAsset']:
        try:
            assetID = i['assetID']
            initialUrl = i['webSite']['initialUrl']
            finalUrl = i['webSite']['finalUrl']
            initialASN = i['asn']['asnID']
            initialHost = i['host']['host']
            existingTags = i['tags']
            finalHost = urlparse(finalUrl).hostname

            print existingTags

>>> [u'Some Tag', u'Some other Tag']
```

Now I need to append an extra value to this variable (existingTags) and resubmit to the API as JSON to update the record. My problem is I don't know 'what' this variable now is - is it a Dict, a List or still JSON?

Once I understand this I can research the right way to append a new value. I've tried treating it as a List using .extend which looks right when printed but is not accepted by the API. Don't think it's a Dict either as I'd expect to see the keys when printed.

```
existingTags.extend(['A New Tag'])
```

Produces 400 error:
[Found invalid item(s) for updating tags:[Some Tag, Some other Tag, A New Tag]]

Resubmitting without touching the existingTags variable works.

Comment: Have you tried `type(existingTags)`? And did you re-serialize `existingTags` before you sent it?

Comment: What do the API's docs say `searchResult['inventoryAsset'][*]['tags']` is?

Comment: Are you sure `'A New Tag'` is a valid item for updating the tags?

Comment: `requests` recursively parses the JSON into Python types, so "still JSON" will never happen. Everything inside there will be a Python data type like a list, dict, string, integer, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and wisdom for a new starter. The answer was in fact that the tag had to already exist in the database (via the UI) to be assigned. So my code was actually working.